# How to mirror (export) CoreData database (entity) to CloudKit Public Database (Swift, UIKit)?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, cloudkit

I have the CoreData entity (Swift, UIKit) that has 6 columns and 4600 rows. My app gets the data from this entity and shows up to the user. But now it is working only at Xcode simulator.

I would like to mirror (export) my CoreData database and upload it to CloudKit Public Database, so that all users who downloads my app from AppStore (in future) could get the access to this data (can fetch any rows from the public database and use it).

But I don't know how make it up (besides I successfully mirrored my second CoreData entity to CloudKit Private Database and it works well). So I have question only with CloudKit **Public** Database.

**My question is:** How to mirror (export) my CoreData database to CloudKit Public Database without creating its from scratch?

Comment: Cloud Kit is not a storage system such that you can hand some data over to your users.

Comment: Seriously? "Each container has a public database whose data is accessible to all users and, if the current user is signed in, a private database whose data is accessible only by the current user." (с) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkitjs/cloudkit/database

Comment: Whether you use privateCloudDatabase or publicCloudDatabase, the user must be logged in.  I use Cloud Kit quite a bit to share data between a macOS application and its iOS counterpart.  But don't listen to me.  Go ahead and do whatever you feel you can do.

Comment: That's OK with user's login. It is intended in that way (only after user logged in). But how to fill the public database up with the data from my CoreData entity? That's the question. Not manually, of course (more than 4500 rows). Manually I can do it using CloudKit dashboard